# Java - This usage of java/lang/ProcessBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;)V can be vulnerable to Command Injection (Sonar)

Tags: java, sonarqube

how to avoid the "This usage of java/lang/ProcessBuilder.([Ljava/lang/String;)V can be vulnerable to Command Injection" sonar message for the code below ?

**UPDATED**

```
void assign(String path, File jarFile) {

   File cert = new File(path, "Cert");
   String password = "123";    

   File script = new File(path, "assign.bat");
   String command = "\"" + script.getAbsolutePath() + "\" " + password
                        + " \"" + cert.getAbsolutePath() + "\""
                        + " \"" + jarFile.getAbsolutePath()     + "\"";

   Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();

}
```

Comment: This isn't vulnerable because you can't inject anything

Comment: I doubt that, "os command here" is actually the command you are running.  What's the actual code doing?  Is the command hard-coded?

Comment: @AndyTurner Depends. Its the same like SQL injection. If you have a fix query without parameters, then it is fine, but when you start adding user parameters, then you're vulnerable. The same when running a command, I guess that's why Sonar complains about that.

Comment: @Tom and this query has no parameters. If this specific code produces a warning, it's perhaps because the String isn't final.

Comment: @AndyTurner "If you have a fix query without parameters, then it is fine" ... that was unclear?

Comment: If your `path` and/or `jarFile` argument(s) are somehow derived from either user input or a separate configuration file then this is valid Command Injection

Comment: Am I missing something?  The query in question seems to have 3 parameters, a password and two paths. These are absolutely potential injection points.

Comment: @Steve The question is:  how to handle these potential injection points ?

Comment: @araraujo, my answer does that - there is still the issue of the incoming **path** value, but constructing the executable's definition is something you can't get around keeping secure by understand the origin of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that you can reason in the current test code that there isn't actually a potential for abuse here, but I doubt that this is production code given a hard coded password of "123".  Code like this tends to morph, and if you leave the potential for injection, you have to know too much about where all of the parameters are coming from to be able to rule out injection.  If you do it the right way, you don't have to be so careful with the parameters.

Also, vulnerability scanners can't be this smart.  Who knows what Sonar is looking for, but it is complaining about this particular variant of ProcessBuilder's constructor.  Maybe it can recognize spaces in the input string and know there are parameters there.  Who knows.  Regardless, there's really no reason not to use the more robust version of the constructor.  I expect doing so will avoid this message.

Just like with SQL, the answer is to pass the individual parameters to ProcessBuilder, like this:

```
void assign(String path, File jarFile) throws IOException {

    File cert = new File(path, "Cert");
    String password = "123";

    File script = new File(path, "assign.bat");
    String[] command = {
            script.getAbsolutePath(),
            password,
            cert.getAbsolutePath(),
            jarFile.getAbsolutePath()
    };

    Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();

}
```

This insures that the code knows the difference between the executable itself and the parameters, and so the executable can not be so easily manipulated.  This also makes this particular code cleaner and easier to read.

Note that even in this case, to be sure this code is safe, you need to know intimately the behavior of **File.getAbsolutePath()** and/or exactly where 'path' and 'jarFile' are coming from.  It's possible that **File** can be manipulated to return something bad from **getAbsolutePath**.  I'm not saying it can, but the fact that I don't know either way is exactly why I'd want to use the multi-string variant of the ProcessBuilder constructor.

UPDATE: So Sonar is still complaining about this form.  It turns out that this new version still uses the same constructor, because the constructor is a varargs constructor that can take "one or more" strings.  I think the original solution I provided actually does solve the injection problem, but Sonar isn't able to recognize the fact that we've separated out the command arguments.

There's a ProcessBuilder constructor that takes a list instead of an array. This version of my example uses that constructor instead.

```
void assign(String path, File jarFile) throws IOException {

    File cert = new File(path, "Cert");
    String password = "123";

    File script = new File(path, "assign.bat");
    String[] command = {
            script.getAbsolutePath(),
            password,
            cert.getAbsolutePath(),
            jarFile.getAbsolutePath()
    };
    List<String> commandList = Arrays.asList(command);

    Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(commandList).start();
}
```

I hope this pleases Sonar.  I'm guessing that this way of building a ProcessBuilder is what it's looking for.

Comment: I made the changes, but the sonar continues sending the same message

Comment: Really?  I don't think it can be the exact same message, because It's using a different constructor.  The signature of the method would have least have had to change.  Are you sure the new code is being tested?  This seems like a classic vulnerability scan issue, and the solution I gave is the standard solution.

Comment: Yikes.  I think you might be right. I had to look up how to interpret a message signature like you have in your question's subject.  That seems to be complaining about the array version of the constructor.  I don't understand that.  I'm going to dig a bit more...

Comment: Ah.  I think I see what's going on.  It is using the same form of constructor, because they are both using single varargs version that takes one or more strings.  I think Sonar is being naive in tagging the use of this constructor even though it is accepting multiple String arguments and is therefore separating the arguments from the executable path.  But...there is a List version of the constructor as well.  Let's try the List version of the constructor.

Comment: Ok, I added a second solution that I hope will please Sonar. - In terms of your comment on your question, let me know if you want some help understanding why this form of building your command (via either of my samples) solves the bulk of the threat of injection.

Comment: I tried the List version, but the sonar displayed "This usage of java/lang/ProcessBuilder.<init>(Ljava/util/List;)V can be vulnerable to Command Injection"

Comment: Wow.  Well, I don't know what to say to that.  I oversee the maintenance of a Java codebase where we run this same sort of scan.  We use Veracode.  Veracode has caught code like your original version many times for us, and we've made this simple change to make the warning go away.  I don't see how you can do it any better than to use either form of the constructor with multiple parameters.  As long as your parameters are being supplied as unique strings, rather than as a single string along with the command, the code should be considered "safe".

Comment: Can you reach out to the people who make Sonar, or to a community that helps support it?  This just seems wrong to me. - one thing you might want to do is post a new question using the List form of your code.  That's a perfectly valid thing to do, especially since your question still contains the old version. - get some fresh eyes on this.